# Calling timeout out with callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function fn1() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hello');
  }, 5000);
}

function fn2() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('goodbye');
  }, 3000);
}
```

a) How to modify above functions using callback so that it can print first "hello" and then "goodbye".
b) i wanted to then print "goodbye" then "hello" and after that just wanted to print "completed".how to do that this as well through callback.

Comment: Since you want to achieve it with callback, you should modify your `fn1` so it takes a `function` (in this case is the `fn2`) as parameter, then invoke it inside the callback function of `setTimeout` of `fn1`. This is the easiest one I have :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question properly but is this more of what you're looking for?

```
    function fn1(callback) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('hello');
      }, 2999);
      callback();
    }

    function fn2() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('goodbye');
      }, 3000);
    }

    fn1(function() {
        fn2();
         setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("completed");
         }, 3001)
    });
```

if so then you have to set the timeout value properly, if you want them to print in that order remember that the values should be sequential too, otherwise you'd have to set new timeouts for fn2 and the following `console.log('Completed')`, like this:

```
    function fn1(callback) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('hello');
      }, 5000);
      callback();
    }

    function fn2() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('goodbye');
      }, 3000);
    }

    fn1(function() { // callback
        setTimeout(function() { // timeout so fn2 fires once fn1 delay is finished
            fn2();
            setTimeout(function() {
                // add your console.log("completed"); or third function
                // here so it fires right after fn2
             }, 3001); // 3000 fn2 timeout + 1ms more so it fires right after
        }, 2001); // the difference between fn1 timeout - fn2 timeout + 1ms so it fires right after
    });
```

Comment: no i don't want to change the timeout value. My question is timeout values will be fixed only but we have to do some callback magic to get my results

Comment: look at the second solution I provided, the timeout values of **fn1** and **fn2** dont change I just added some extra timeouts in the callback. The first one to delay fn2 2000ms which is the difference between fn1 and fn2 and +1ms more so it fires right after fn1 and the nested timeout is so **completed** has fires 1ms more than the timeout of fn2 so it fires right after, I will modify the nested timeout so can add your third function there.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, when you pass a callback into another function, you only pass the reference to the function (without executing it, thus without the parenthesis ()).
And on the return we check if the reference to the function was passed (better to check with lodash or _ isFunction method because it may cause an error if foo is not a function)

```js
const fn1 = (foo = false) => {
  setTimeout(console.log('goodbye'), 300);

  return foo && foo()
}

const fn2 = (foo = false) => {
  setTimeout( console.log('hello'), 500);
  
  return foo && foo()
}


fn1(fn2)
fn2(fn1)
```